# jQuery plugin returning "Cannot read property of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, undefined

I'm trying to do something i've done numerous times. I can't figure out why this isn't working. No matter how i write the jQuery code, it doesn't work. `menuitems[i].action()` just does NOT work. Below is **Example 1** in which this example, no matter what item is clicked it returns the last item's action (in this example it's the `alert('Forward!')`). The 2nd returns undefined property. The full error below.

My jQuery plugin is called like this (examples below are what happen with this same call):

```
$('p').contextMenu([
    {
        name:'Back',
        action:function(){
            alert('Back!');
        },
        icon:'http://cdn.iconfinder.net/data/icons/crystalproject/16x16/actions/agt_back.png'
    },
    {
        name:'Forward',
        action:function(){
            alert('Forward!');
        },
        icon:'http://cdn.iconfinder.net/data/icons/crystalproject/16x16/actions/agt_forward.png'
    }
]);
```

**Example 1:**

```
for (i in menuitems){
    $('<li/>',{
        'html':'<img src="'+menuitems[i].icon+'">'+menuitems[i].name,
        'class':o.itemClass,
        'click':function(){
            menuitems[i].action();
        }
    }).appendTo('.'+o.listClass);
}
```

This returns an alert with Forward! no matter which item, Back or Forward, is clicked.

**Example 2:**

```
var len = menuitems.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    $('<li/>',{
        'html':'<img src="'+menuitems[i].icon+'">'+menuitems[i].name,
        'click':function(){
            menuitems[i].action();
        },
        'class':o.itemClass
    }).appendTo('.'+o.listClass);
}
```

I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'action' of undefined

Other random things i tried were detaching the click and reattaching it outside of that `appendTo()` block, changed `action()` to `newtest()` to make sure it wasn't conflicting with any built in keywords. I also tried doing a `$('body').append('<li>{blah blah}</li>').find('li').click(function(){/*blah blah*/});` but it still returned the same thing. I'm outta ideas!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: Have any recommendations on a debugger? I'm just using Chrome's inspector

Comment: Same error in Firebug...

Comment: The exact one in Firebug is: menuitems[i] is undefined
file:///C:/Users/oscargodson/Documents/jquery_apps/contextmenu.html
Line 65

Comment: Awh... one thing to note tho guys, if i add like `var test = menuitems[i]` it's not longer `undefined` but then it does the thing where it only calls the very last action() on every item (like i said above, it'd be alert('Forward!')

Comment: Set a breakpoint before you enter the loop and inspect `menuitems`

Comment: I dunno... i mean, it appears to break when it enters the click() function. Even if i put it into a var outside of the loop, inside of the loop, or anywhere. If i dont put it into a var at all it's undefined inside of click. Im outta ideas. And when i mean "break" i mean basically remove all the objects except the last one

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that "i" is incremented, so by the time the click event is executed the value of i equals len.
One possible solution is to capture the value of i inside a function:

```
var len = menuitems.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    (function(i) {
      $('<li/>',{
          'html':'<img src="'+menuitems[i].icon+'">'+menuitems[i].name,
          'click':function(){
              menuitems[i].action();
          },
          'class':o.itemClass
      }).appendTo('.'+o.listClass);
    })(i);
}
```

In the above sample, the anonymous function creates a new scope which captures the current value of i, so that when the click event is triggered the local variable is used instead of the i from the for loop.

Comment: Genius! Duh, i can't believe i didn't think about this... Thanks, this will work. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Usually that problem is that in the last iteration you have an empty object or undefine object. use console.log() inside you cicle to check that this doent happend.

Sometimes a prototype in some place add an extra element.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with 'parallax' plugin.
I changed jQuery librery version to `*jquery-1.6.4*` from `*jquery-1.10.2*.`
And error cleared.